# What test should I run before performing a runtime upgrade?

Tags: runtime, upgrade

If I'm running a chain in production and I've upgraded some pallets in my runtime, what steps do I need to take to make sure my runtime will run without fail when it is included in my live chain?

Answer (score 4):

Peeking at the release checklist of Polkadot (or any other professional substrate-based chain) is a good insight into what components you need to look out for. Here's [an example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/4902) from the 0.9.17 version. I would summarize the most important ones as:

1. Update `spec_version` and `impl_version` accordingly. If you are not sure when to bump them, read [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_version/struct.RuntimeVersion.html).
2. Update `transaction_version` accordingly. Read more about [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_version/struct.RuntimeVersion.html).
3. If you added new calls, and you are using `pallet-proxy`, you probably need to check your proxy [`ProxyType`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_proxy/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.ProxyType), most notable, how it implements to [`InstanceCallFilter`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.InstanceFilter.html).
4. Finally, if your pallets have altered their storage in any way that could cause storage to be un-decoable, you need to have some storage migrations, and you need to make sure they are executed, and you better test them since you only get one shot at doing it in production. There are lots of resources about this, and as mentioned earlier, [`try-runtime`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/enum.Command.html) has a bunch of commands that help with this. There are also some [tutorials](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/try-runtime/) about it in the substrate developer hub.